# Form action does not function properly

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to figure out why my form action URL is acting as a Relative URL instead of an Absolute URL.

I want it to go directly to ”http://www.formsubmit.co/el/cowuku” but instead it goes to github.com/project-name/”http://www.formsubmit.co/el/cowuku”

```
<form target="_blank" action=”http://www.formsubmit.co/el/cowuku” method="post">
        <div class="container col-sm-4">
          <!-- Name -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="message" type="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here" required>
          </div>
          <!-- Email -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
          </div>
          <!-- Text Area -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Text Area</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <!-- HoneyPot -->
          <input name="_formsubmit_id" type="text" style="display:none">
          <!-- Template Style -->
          <input type="hidden" name="_autoresponse" value="Thanks for your submission">
          <!-- Button Submit -->
          <input class="btn btn-primary my-4" type="submit" value="Submit Message">
        </div>
      </form>
```

I'm not sure what to try

Comment: Duplicate of [inline nav example doesn't work](/q/24247572/4642212) or any of [these](/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+curly+quotes+is%3Aa) or [these](/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+smart+quotes+is%3Aa).

Comment: @SebastianSimon How is this a duplicate??

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMushref Because the problem is caused by the exact same behavior of how HTML attributes are interpreted, and it has the exact same answer and solution.

Comment: That's not how duplication works, but sure.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMushref Do we need a new question about the same typo for every single HTML attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of this ” character, it's diferent then this ".
This should work

```
action="http://www.formsubmit.co/el/cowuku"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arek, `target="_blank"` Only works for `<a>` tag. The `action` is supposed to point to your backend file that is responsible for saving the form's data.

FormSubmit won't help you with that. So you have 2 options:

1- Create the form yourself using HTML and any backend language (PHP). 
2- Delete that entire form, replace it with `<a href="http://www.formsubmit.co/el/cowuku" target="_blank"/> Click here /<a>` to open a new tab with the form.

Learn more about the tags and attributes from this source: https://htmlreference.io/